# Is Big-O Notation also calculated from the functions used?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time, big-o

I'm learning about Big-O Notation and algorithms to improve my interview skills, but I don't quite understand how to get the time complexity.

Suppose I want to sum all the elements of the following list.

```
std::vector<int> myList = {1,2,3,4,5} ;
```

Case 1:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int it: myList)
{
  sum += it;
}
```

Case 2:

```
int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(myList), std::end(myList), 0);
```

Case 1 is O(N), and case 2 is apparently O(1), but I'm sure those functions do some kind of iteration, so the question is whether Big-O notation is calculated only from of the written code of that block or also of the functions used.

Comment: "_and case 2 is apparently O(1)_": Where did you get this from? It is obviously impossible to sum `N` things in better than `O(N)` time.

Comment: Your doubts are justified. Re-read the introduction to this Big-O stuff, in particular when it talks about the imagined machine it executes in. That said, you find the complexity of C++ algorithms in the standard or on cppreference.com.

Comment: @user17732522 "*It is obviously impossible to sum `N` things in better than `O(N)` time.*" To play the pedant, it depends what you know about those `N` things. Summing all integers in the range [1,N], for example, could be done in O(1).

Comment: @scohe001 Well ok. Summing `N` things each independently with at least two possible states is obviously not possible to do in better than `O(N)` worst-case time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you talk about big-O, you have to talk in respect of some unit of data being processed.  Both your case 1 and case 2 are O(N) where N is the number of items in the container: the unit is an `int`.

You tend to want the unit - and N to be the count of - the thing that's likely to grow/vary most in your program.  For example, if you're talking about processing names in phonebooks, then the number of names should be N; even though the length of individual names is also somewhat variable, there's no expected pattern of increasing average name length as your program handles larger phonebooks.

Similarly, if your program had to handle an arbitrary number of containers that tended to be roughly the same length, then your unit might be a container, and then you could think of your code - case 1 and case 2 - as being big-O O(1) with respect to the number of containers, because whether there are 0, 1, 10 or a million other containers lying around someone in your program, you're only processing the one - `myList`.  But, any individual `accumulate` call is O(N) with respect to any individual container's `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

I think this example should give you an idea.

```
int sum(std::vector<int> const& list)
{
   int result = 0;
   for( elem const& : list )
   { 
       result += elem;
   }
   return result;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> test = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    

   // O(n)
   int sum1 = 0;
   for( elem const& : test )
   {
      sum1 += elem;
   }

  // O(???)
  int sum2 = sum(test);
}
```

Comment: An idea of what? I don't see what you answer is intended to convey.

Comment: @user17732522 I'd hazard that it's meant to convey that the processing internal to a function call must be the same as the processing if you code the iteration yourself, so you can reason about how the big-O efficiencies compare....  Might or might not help it click for OP (and others).

Comment: @TonyDelroy that's of course correct. To put it simply, Big-O notation would be pretty useless if it would return to number of function calls, since then any program would be O(1): `int main(){ run_my_program(); }`

Answer (score 1):

For an evaluation of the time complexity, it makes more sense to count the operations that take constant time. Hence `sum` is not a particularly good candidate unless

- the sums are always done on the same number of elements, or
- the distribution of the sum lengths is known and independent of the circumstances where the calls are made (to avoid any bias).

Such evaluations are rather unusual.

Answer (score 0):

> case 2 is apparently O(1)

Says who? [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/) says about `accumulate`:

> **Complexity**
> Linear in the distance between first and last.

Which is the same O(N) as your case 1 code.

(I also checked [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) but in this case it doesn't say something about the complexity.)